MobX mixing autorun() and runInAction() to limit reactions
Suppose I want printSum() to run when observableMain changes, but don't want it to react to observableSesondary. 
Code below will trigger on both (which is undesirable):
@observable observableMain = 0;
@observable observableSecondary = 0;

constructor() { makeObservable(this); }

printSum(val) {
  console.log(val + this.observableSecondary);
}

subscribeSum() {
  autorun(() => this.printSum(this.observableMain));
}
...
this.subscribeSum(); // 0, OK
this.observableMain = 1; // 1, OK
this.observableSecondary = 1; // 2, not what I want 

Solutions I've tried (both seem to work):
1. use runInAction() during access to observableSecondary:
printSum(val) {
  runInAction(() => console.log(val + this.observableSecondary));
}

subscribeSum() {
  autorun(() => this.printSum(this.obsevableMain));
}

2. use explicit reaction() instead of autorun()
printSum(val) {
  () => console.log(val + this.observableSecondary);
}

subscribeSum() {
  reaction(() => this.observableMain, val => this.printSum(val));
}

But I wonder if both soultions are equivalent and safe to use? Is it a supposed behavior of MobX that runInAction() during autorun() skips the tracking of side effects?
